# Как сделать так, что бы все *.php файлы открывались по ссылке *.png?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, php, mod_rewrite

Подскажите пожалуйста, как с помощью .htaccess и mod_rewrite сделать так, что бы все *.php файлы открывались по ссылке *.png?

P.S. Именно для каталога /image/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

mod_rewrite

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule image/(.*)\.png$ /image/$1.php [L]
```

на вскидку, можно конечно редиректить на 1 статический файл, например:

```
RewriteRule image/(.*)$ /image/image.php?file=$1 [L]
```

а внутри скрипта уже пытатся вывести нужный файл.

Answer (score -1):

А еще есть codeigniter, в котором можно к каждому контролеру прибавить любое расширение, хоть index.hfgfgf

Читай [добавление суффикса PHP](http://codeigniter.su/general/urls.html)

Comment: маршрутизация здесь ни причем...

Comment: @Vfvtnjd значит я не правильно понял тз